# Java i don't know the type of passed function value

Tags: java

I have a function in Java

```
public static void printC(int val){
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

`Val` can be `string`,`int`,`BigInt` etc.How can i make the function to take whatever type is given?

Comment: `Object` works here.

Comment: @markspace thanks for yer ineffable help!

Comment: Actually, you should use generics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use generics.

```
static <T> void printC(T val) {
    System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: Why not objects?

Comment: Read upon objects and primitives types.

Comment: Also read about generics [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Comment: Thanks for thy intergalatic help

Comment: Object still works ... however I would go with generic type for the benefits mentioned in Oracle Documentation.

Comment: I have to agree with John because Java generics were designed specifically for these types of situation.